# How to run same syntax on multiple spss files

Tags: file-io, syntax, spss

I have 24 spss files in .sav format in a single folder. All these files have the same structure. I want to run the same syntax on all these files. Is it possible to write a code in spss for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SPSSINC PROCESS FILES` user submitted command to do this or write your own macro. So first lets create some very simple fake data to work with.

```
*FILE HANDLE save /NAME = "Your Handle Here!".

*Creating some fake data.
DATA LIST FREE / X Y.
BEGIN DATA
1 2
3 4
END DATA.
DATASET NAME Test.
SAVE OUTFILE = "save\X1.sav".
SAVE OUTFILE = "save\X2.sav".
SAVE OUTFILE = "save\X3.sav".
EXECUTE.

*Creating a syntax file to call.
DO IF $casenum = 1.
PRINT OUTFILE = "save\TestProcess_SHOWN.sps" /"FREQ X Y.".
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

Now we can use the `SPSSINC PROCESS FILES` command to specify the sav files in the folder and apply the `TestProcess_SHOWN.sps` syntax to each of those files.

```
*Now example calling the syntax.
SPSSINC PROCESS FILES INPUTDATA="save\X*.sav"  
SYNTAX="save\TestProcess_SHOWN.sps" 
OUTPUTDATADIR="save" CONTINUEONERROR=YES
VIEWERFILE= "save\Results.spv" CLOSEDATA=NO
MACRONAME="!JOB"
/MACRODEFS ITEMS.
```

Comment: hi! SPSSINC seems to be an extension bundle . I have dowloaded it and was trying to install it .. but i get in an error unable to install the extension bundle in the pathfile.

Comment: @user2717955 - and I can't help much with that. My only guess would be you need to be logged on as an administrator when installing the extensions.

Comment: hi!I was able to install the plugin. However, I also need a command line to import 24 excel sheets in an excelworkbook (numbered from 1-24) into spss as separate dataset files named 1.sav,2.sav....24.sav. Each of these files are in similar format only the number of rows to be imported differ across files.  Then a similar recoding need to be done across all the files.             Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Another (less advanced) way is to use the command `INSERT`. To do so, repeatedly `GET` each sav-file, run the syntax with `INSERT`, and sav the file. Probably something like this:

```
get 'file1.sav'.
insert file='syntax.sps'.
save outf='file1_v2.sav'.

dataset close all.
get 'file2.sav'.
insert file='syntax.sps'.
save outf='file2_v2.sav'.

etc etc.
```

Good luck!

Comment: +1 - You can wrap this up in a macro to make the repetitive calling of the same commands simpler as well, especially if the list of file names is a convenient counter like you show.

Answer (score 0):

If the Syntax you need to run is completely independent of the files then you can either use: `INSERT FILE = 'Syntax.sps'` or put the code in a macro e.g.

```
Define !Syntax ()
 * Put Syntax here
!EndDefine.
```

You can then run either of these 'manually';

```
get file = 'file1.sav'.
insert file='syntax.sps'.
save outfile ='file1_v2.sav'.
```

Or

```
get file = 'file1.sav'.
!Syntax.
save outfile ='file1_v2.sav'.
```

Or if the files follow a reasonably strict naming structure you can embed either of the above in a simple bit of python;

```
Begin Program.
imports spss
for i in range(0, 24 + 1):
 syntax = "get file = 'file" + str(i) + ".sav.\n"
 syntax += "insert file='syntax.sps'.\n"
 syntax += "save outfile ='file1_v2.sav'.\n"
 print syntax
 spss.Submit(syntax)
End Program.
```